# Countable models of the theory of finite cycles.

Tags: logic, model-theory

A cycle in an set $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is a structure (X,S), where $S$ is a permutation such that $S(x_i)=x_{i+1}$ for $i<n$ and $S(x_n)=x_1$.

Now consider the theory $T:=\{ \varphi: \varphi \text{ is true in all finite cycles } (X,S)\}$. What is the shape of the infinite countable models of this theory?

Of course every infinite countable model of the theory of $(\mathbb{Z},S)$ where $S$ is the succesor function is a model of $T$. Those have the form $I\times \mathbb{Z}$ where $I$ is a countable set. Are there any others?

Comment: I wanted to proof that those were all the models, but I don't see why we cannot have an infinite product of cycles of finite length.

Comment: HINT: one of the sentences in $T$, for example, is "If there is a five-element cycle, then there are exactly five elements in the universe" (things would be different if we looked at the theory of *disjoint unions of* finite cycles).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Now I see it! I had a similar idea but didn't know how to express it properly. This implies that all the cycles in the infinite model are infinite and hence all the models are exactly the models of $Th(\mathbb{Z},S)$. Thanks